# Problem regarding the node-fetch api. Specifically, when attempting to use fetch to retrieve JSON data

Tags: node.js, api, promise, request, node-fetch

Code below retrieves the JSON data without any problems.

```
     app.get('/startgame', (req, res) => {
     res.send('Welcome To The Start Of The Game')
     fetch("https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/new/shuffle/deck_count=1")
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then(json => console.log(json)) 
    })
```

Code below returns undefined when I do console.log(json). The only difference between these two blocks of code are the squiggly brackets on the bottom block of code. I would like to know why exactly is this happening. My understanding is that they should both produce the same result.

```
   app.get('/startgame', (req, res) => {
     res.send('Welcome To The Start Of The Game')
     fetch("https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/new/shuffle/?deck_count=1")
    .then((res) => {res.json()})
    .then((json) => {console.log(json)})
```

})

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that this syntax:

```
() => foo()
```

Is short for:

```
() => { return foo(); }
```

On this line in your code:

```
.then((res) => { res.json() })
```

you are no longer returning the result of `res.json()`. You need to explicitly use `return` when you use curly braces:

```
.then((res) => { return res.json(); })
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
.then((res) => res.json())
```